# Trouble Deserializing JSON values to Type<T>

Tags: c#, json, api, rest

My type is Report:

```
 [DataContract]
internal class Report
{
    [DataMember]
    internal string created_at;

    internal string Created_at
    {
        get { return created_at; }
        set { created_at = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string eligible_id;

    internal string Eligible_id
    {
        get { return eligible_id; }
        set { eligible_id = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    private int[] known_issues;

    public int[] Known_issues
    {
        get { return known_issues; }
        set { known_issues = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string response_code;

    internal string Response_code
    {
        get { return response_code; }
        set { response_code = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string response_description;

    internal string Response_description
    {
        get { return response_description; }
        set { response_description = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string agency_qualifier_code;

    internal string Agency_qualifier_code
    {
        get { return agency_qualifier_code; }
        set { agency_qualifier_code = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string agency_qualifier_description;

    internal string Agency_qualifier_description
    {
        get { return agency_qualifier_description; }
        set { agency_qualifier_description = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string reject_reason_code;

    internal string Reject_reason_code
    {
        get { return reject_reason_code; }
        set { reject_reason_code = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string reject_reason_description;

    internal string Reject_reason_description
    {
        get { return reject_reason_description; }
        set { reject_reason_description = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string follow_up_action_code;

    internal string Follow_up_action_code
    {
        get { return follow_up_action_code; }
        set { follow_up_action_code = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string folow_up_description;

    internal string Folow_up_description
    {
        get { return folow_up_description; }
        set { folow_up_description = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    internal string details;

    internal string Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { details = value; }
    }
}
```

When I try to get my JSON object from API calls, I get:

[image]

When I try to deserialize this object and place it within my Type Report, I keep getting blank values, as if nothing was placed within my Report Object.  Why is that?

```
public static Tuple<string, string, bool> eligible(string ptFirst, string ptLast, string ptPolicy, string DOB, string DOS, string payerID)
    {            
        string apiSecret = "##### ###### #######";
        string providerOrgName = "###############################";
        string ptPolicyID = ptPolicy;
        string ptFirstName = ptFirst;
        string ptLastName = ptLast;
        string ptDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string ptDOS = Convert.ToDateTime(DOS).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string serviceType = "18";
        string NPI = "#####################";       

        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.com/v1.5/coverage/all?api_key="
            + apiSecret + "&payer_id=" + payerID + "&service_provider_organization_name=" + providerOrgName + "&provider_npi=" + NPI +
            "&member_id=" + ptPolicyID + "&member_first_name=" + ptFirstName + "&member_last_name=" + ptLastName +
            "&member_dob=" + ptDOB + "&date=" + DOS + "&service_type=" + serviceType + "&format=REST");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string response271 = response.Content;   
>>>>    //This is the JSON object from my first picture         
        MessageBox.Show(response271);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Report result = new Report();            
        result = js.Deserialize<Report>(response271); 
>>>>    //This is the box that comes up blank, my second picture.
        MessageBox.Show(result.eligibility_id);

        return Tuple.Create("test", "test", false);          
 }
```

> When I call this line

Messagebox.Show(result.eligiblity_id);

> I get a blank string back.

[image]

I am new to using JSON Objects but I have been trying to figure this out for two days so i am hoping someone can direct me on where to go from here.

Comment: How come you have used DataContactSerializer annotations on your JSON serialized entity?

Comment: @chris.ellis I was trying to follow some answered question I saw here on StackOverflow and thought that it somehow organized the JSON into an object I can access.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Lola Thanks for the suggestion, however, the message still comes back as an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Json.Net.

```
Change result = js.Deserialize<Report>(response271);
```

to

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(response271);
```

### Edit to answer follow up question

[Link to Json.Net site](https://json.codeplex.com/)

error is an object in the json response so you need to add:

```
[JsonProperty]
public Error error {get;set;}
```

to your Report class and make an error class:

```
public class Error
{
    [JsonProperty]
    internal string response_code;

    internal string Response_code
    {
        get { return response_code; }
        set { response_code = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string response_description;

    internal string Response_description
    {
        get { return response_description; }
        set { response_description = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string agency_qualifier_code;

    internal string Agency_qualifier_code
    {
        get { return agency_qualifier_code; }
        set { agency_qualifier_code = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string agency_qualifier_description;

    internal string Agency_qualifier_description
    {
        get { return agency_qualifier_description; }
        set { agency_qualifier_description = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string reject_reason_code;

    internal string Reject_reason_code
    {
        get { return reject_reason_code; }
        set { reject_reason_code = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string reject_reason_description;

    internal string Reject_reason_description
    {
        get { return reject_reason_description; }
        set { reject_reason_description = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string follow_up_action_code;

    internal string Follow_up_action_code
    {
        get { return follow_up_action_code; }
        set { follow_up_action_code = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string folow_up_description;

    internal string Folow_up_description
    {
        get { return folow_up_description; }
        set { folow_up_description = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string details;

    internal string Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { details = value; }
    }
}
```

This will be accessed like result.error.details

Comment: Doing this gives me an error, so I attempted to try it with a type cast:

      result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(response271); and it worked but only when I called created_at..... do I need to do something else for the second set of curly brackets in the JSON response?